# QLineEdit and Escape Signal

Tags: qt, signals, qlineedit

I want to create a class which is derived from `QLineEdit`,but I can not assign a signal for Escape button.

The code was working until I add the `cancel_signal()` and then

> LNK2019/LNK1120

errors are appeared.

How can I assign a signal for Escape button?

---

**LineEditAlphaNum.h:**

```
#ifndef _LINEEDIT_ALPHA_NUM_
#define _LINEEDIT_ALPHA_NUM_

#include <QtGui>

class LineEditAlphaNum : public QLineEdit
{
public:
    LineEditAlphaNum(QWidget* parent);

    void setPrevNextWidget(QWidget* prev, QWidget* next);

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);

private:
    void keyLogic(QString& str, int key);

    int keyIndex;
    int lastKey;

    QWidget* m_pPrev;
    QWidget* m_pNext;

signals:
    void cancel_signal();
};

#endif // _LINEEDIT_ALPHA_NUM_
```

---

**LineEditAlphaNum.cpp:**

```
#include "LineEditAlphaNum.h"

LineEditAlphaNum::LineEditAlphaNum(QWidget *parent) :
    QLineEdit(parent),
    keyIndex(0),
    lastKey(0)
{
}

void LineEditAlphaNum::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    QString str = text();

    switch( e->key() )
    {
    case Qt::Key_Escape:
        emit cancel_signal();
    case Qt::Key_Up:
        m_pPrev->setFocus(Qt::OtherFocusReason);
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Down:
        m_pNext->setFocus(Qt::OtherFocusReason);
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Right:
        keyIndex = 0;
        lastKey = e->key();
        break;
    case Qt::Key_0:
    case Qt::Key_1:
    case Qt::Key_2:
    case Qt::Key_3:
    case Qt::Key_4:
    case Qt::Key_5:
    case Qt::Key_6:
    case Qt::Key_7:
    case Qt::Key_8:
    case Qt::Key_9:
        keyLogic(str, e->key());
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Backspace:
        str.remove(str.size()-1, 1);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    setText(str);
}

void LineEditAlphaNum::keyLogic(QString& str, int key)
{
    char* Keys[] = {"0 ",
                    "1",
                    "2ABC",
                    "3DEF",
                    "4GHI",
                    "5JKL",
                    "6MNO",
                    "7PQRS",
                    "8TUV",
                    "9WXYZ"};

    char* keymap = Keys[ key - Qt::Key_0 ];
    int length = strlen(keymap);

    if ( lastKey == key )
    {
        keyIndex = (++keyIndex) % length;
        str.remove( str.size()-1, 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        keyIndex = 0;
        lastKey = key;
    }

    str.append( QChar( keymap[keyIndex] ) );
}
void LineEditAlphaNum::setPrevNextWidget(QWidget* prev, QWidget* next)
{
    m_pPrev = prev;
    m_pNext = next;
}
```

Comment: Note that if you want the user to be able to move the cursor and delete any character (not only the last one) using the backspace and delete key, you should forward the left, right, backspace and delete key to the super class event handler.

Comment: Also note that if your "linked list of widgets" (as I suppose you have here) isn't cyclic but you have null pointers at both ends, you should check the pointer for being null before accessing a member function (iIn your cases for up/down keys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got this linkage error because the signal is a C++ function, which hasn't been defined. This is normally done by the `moc`, which doesn't generate some code of your class.

Whenever you want to use signals and slots in `QObject` derived classes or need something else which uses the `QMetaObject`, you need to add

```
Q_OBJECT
```

after the opening curly braces of your class definition.

Note that when you add this macro, you also need to **manually run qmake**, since the QtCreator tries to be smart and skips this build step if the `.pro` file hasn't changed. But the pre- or absence of the `Q_OBJECT` macro has to be considered as a change for qmake, since `moc` (the meta object compiler) needs to run over all files having a `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class definition.

Comment: @amcali No problem :) What I suggest is: Make yourself a check list of things you should check / do whenever your program doesn't compile. This list could contain: Insert `Q_OBJECT` macro in QObject derived classes, manually re-run `qmake`, completely rebuild your application, ... (Somethimes one can't explain some compiler / linker errors and they are caused by some missing dependencies in the Makefile or whatever...)